# |NSScreen mainScreen| not updating when keyboard/mouse focus goes to other monitor?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a global app that reports back info about the current textfield. I have set it up so every time I click my mouse, I run:

```
NSLog(@"Screen:%f,%f", [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width, [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height);
```

But when I put keyboard focus in a textfield on the one screen, then click the mouse (repeatedly) in that same textfield, the `[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]` often reports the wrong screen dimensions! It gives me the dimensions of the other display.

The Apple docs say:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> The main screen is not necessarily the same screen that contains the
>   menu bar or has its origin at (0, 0). The main screen refers to the
>   screen containing the window that is currently receiving keyboard
>   events. It is the main screen because it is the one with which the
>   user is most likely interacting.

This says that the screen with keyboard focus is always the main screen. I'm giving it keyboard focus and mouse focus. So why am I getting the *other* screen 50% of the time?

Is this a bug in [NSScreen mainScreen]? Do I have to force a recalculation somehow? Is there any other way to get the dimensions of the display that has keyboard focus?

Answer (score 7):

> This says that the screen with keyboard focus is always the main screen. I'm giving it keyboard focus and mouse focus. So why am I getting the other screen 50% of the time?

I know this is nit picking, but it technically says that the main screen is the screen that contains the **window** that has key focus. So if you have a window spanning two screens with a text field and the window's origin is on screen 1, but the text field is on the part of the window that is on screen 2, and the text field is focused, the main screen will still be screen 1.

Comment: Right, I noticed that too and did resize the window down to a very small size and put it entirely on one screen. Still has the issue.

Comment: To confirm, you could also check the result of [window screen].

Comment: Do you mean [theWindowIamInteractingWith screen]? This is a global app, the window belongs to a different app, so I don't think I have that info. If you meant something else, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "global app". So the code with the logging is in a different process for the window being clicked? Then you must be observing the events via some out of band mechanism. Perhaps the events are coming to your process in an order the has them occurring before the screen main status updated. You could try using a timer that constantly logs instead to see if it's an event ordering issue.

Comment: Right, the window belongs to Safari or Finder or Chrome or any app. So I can't access [window screen] directly. I have figured something out with the Accessibility API, but it seems as if the Apple Docs stating `[NSScreen mainScreen]` == "window that is currently receiving keyboard events" is simply wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To get the screen containing the mouse:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/104529-current-mouse-screen.html